# Prevent shift of content when modal is opened/closed

Tags: html, css

Please reference http://imdarrien.com/#

When you open a modal, say profile, then close it again using esc, you can see that the content shifts left when the sidebar is re-added. How can I prevent that shift? I've tried adding `overflow-y:visible` to html but the shift still occurs.

Comment: Try `overflow-y:scroll;` instead.

Comment: Please make sure you post have all information to reproduce problem inline.

Answer (score 1):

When you click to open the popup, `remodal-is-locked` added to the `html` tag. The class removed after the fade-out animation was **ended**.

The problem is that when you close the popup, the html's `overflow:hidden` still exist because the class `remodal-is-locked` so in this situation both of the scrollbars (`html` or the `popup`) are showing, so the content is in specific position. Just after the animation wan ended you remove the class and `html` "get" his scollbar again.

P.S. The problem is in the `remodal.min.js` script so you have to edit this file. I try to point you to the specific place although the script was minified.

[image: figure]

**red** - the `close` function.

**green** - the callback function, **after** the animation was ended.

**blue** - the function which remove the class `remodal-is-locked` from the html.

---

**The solution**

Remove the class when you **start** the fade-out animation. (The **purple** arrow)

Comment: So I need to move `f()` above `b`? This is the modal script I'm using. https://github.com/VodkaBears/Remodal/blob/master/dist/remodal.js